# My toon shader is glowing

Tags: shaders

I was making this character- please ignore the imperfections- and after I applied the Toon BSDF shader to the skin, at some of the parts of the body, the shader started glowing. I have no background, there is one spotlight on the scene. There are no materials which emit any sort of light. The glowing effect is present in the renders too.

[image: The model]

Daniel

Comment: It may be indirect light. What does it look like with more samples? If it's suitable for your project you may reduce the diffuse bounce to 0. See if it helps.

Comment: Setting the diffuse to 0 worked! Thanks, you saved my day! :)